# Ugly Purple dotted border on active

Tags: css, border

got another problem with my new design:
!
[Ugly border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZLWj.png)

It's on a slider called FlexSlider and i've changed the arrows. How can i get that border away, border:0px doesn't help.

Comment: not clear (through firebug not showing any property) may be in the css that came along with script, you will find classes or style proerties which is responsible for that.

Comment: .flexslider {width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border:0px; outline: none; }
.flexslider .slides li { width:380px; height:250px; display: none; margin-top:-30px; } /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {max-width: 100%; display: block;}

Comment: That's the code for the main slider. Anyone ideas?

Comment: what browser are you seeing it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `border:0px` doesn't help, it might be an `outline.` Try `outline:none`.

See: http://css-tricks.com/829-removing-the-dotted-outline/

Answer (score 1):

```
a#next_and_previous{
    outline: none;
}
```